# Snapping for windows phone

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-phone-8, snapping

There is one snapping feature in Windows 8 os(for desktops).

I want to know is that Snapping feature supported by the Windows Phone 8.

If yes, how we can implement that.

I searched in Google but not able to find the satisfy answers.

Comment: What do you mean with "snapping feature"? To which product do you refer where a "snapping feature" is available?

Comment: Elaborate the question

Comment: Do you mean the screen layout where two apps run side by side, one of them 320 (logical) pixels wide? That does not exist on a phone. The reason should be obvious when you look at one, noticing the size of its screen.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you can't have an app snapped in Windows Phone like you do in Windows 8. Not even you can have two apps sharing screen.